# PHP strpos validation

Tags: php

I am using the strpos function to validate a url that is submitted by a user and I want to make sure I'm not missing anything that would allow the user to bypass the validation and submit a url that is inappropriate.

Take the following as an example, if I only want a user to be able to input a url associated with the youtube domain, I don't want them to be able to put a wildcard (*) or something in that would "trick" the strpos function.

```
$url = $request->input('url');

// Check if Youtube url is found

if (strpos($url, 'http://youtube.com') > -1)
{
    // some code    
}

// some code
```

Thanks!

Comment: You're also going to have to take into account URL shorteners, too

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`strpos` returns false when in a not found condition and `0` if the string appears in the first column, which also looks like `false` to PHP, so it would be more accurate to use `===` or `!==`

```
$url = $request->input('url');
// Check if Youtube url is found

if (strpos($url, 'http://youtube.com') !== FALSE)
{
    // some code when youtube is found in url
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You would be better off using a Regular expression.

```
^(https?\:\/\/)?(www\.)?(youtube\.com|youtu\.?be)\/.+$
```

Try it out.

Comment: huge great hammer to crack a peanut

Comment: Follow up to @andrewsi comment on the question.

Comment: And what about the other 1000 possible url shortners that are out there

Comment: Well, i figured the OP doesn't care about that. And the suggestion was valid, youtu.be is the official shortener for youtube. It's owned by Alphabet. Such hate..

Comment: No hate, just thinking ahead. I dont agree that regex is a solution for everything, When a simple strpos or similiar will do it is not necessary to load a whole regex engine. K.I.S.S. is my mantra

Comment: I can include some text that gives direction on how to in put it (i.e. "only use http://youtube.com or http://youtu.be"). So, I don't need to include the universe of shorteners...plus, I envision the user just going to the youtube video, click "share" and use the provided url.

Answer (score 0):

Remember to test with type safe equation.

`strpos` will find the position of first occurrence in the string. So 
if there is a match in the beginning of string (position 0)

```
if (strpos($url, 'http://youtube.com') > -1)
```

will return 0 which will be interpreted as `false`. You're in trouble here.

Instead, do it type safely:

```
if (strpos($url, 'http://youtube.com') !== false)
```

This means no matter where in the string your substring is found, it will be considered true and you know there is a match.

Comment: No, `strpos` returns either the position of the first occurrence, or `boolean false`. So we really just need to know if it's false. In every other case it is "true" to us, position of the needle found in the haystack.